# Python Ignoring What is in a list?

Tags: python, function

Working on a project for CS1 that prints out a grid made of 0s and adds shapes of certain numbered sizes to it. Before it adds a shape it needs to check if A) it will fit on the grid and B) if something else is already there. The issue I am having is that when run, the function that checks to make sure placement for the shapes is valid will always do the first and second shapes correctly, but any shape added after that will only "see" the first shape added when looking for a collision. I checked to see if it wasnt taking in the right list after the first time but that doesnt seem to be it.  Example of the issue....

> Shape Sizes = 4, 3, 2, 1

Python Outputs:

```
4 4 4 4 1 2 3 0 
4 4 4 4 2 2 3 0 
4 4 4 4 3 3 3 0 
4 4 4 4 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

It **Should** Output:

```
4 4 4 4 3 3 3 1
4 4 4 4 3 3 3 0
4 4 4 4 3 3 3 0
4 4 4 4 2 2 0 0
0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

What's going on here? Full Code is below...

```
def binCreate(size):
    binlist = [[0 for col in range(size)] for row in range(size)]
    return binlist

def binPrint(lst):
    for row in range(len(lst)):
        for col in range(len(lst[row])):
            print(lst[row][col], end = " ")
        print()

def itemCreate(fileName):
    lst = []
    for i in open(fileName):
        i = i.split()
        lst = i
    lst = [int(i) for i in lst]
    return lst

def main():
    size = int(input("Bin Size: "))
    fileName = str(input("Item Size File: "))
    binList = binCreate(size)
    blockList = itemCreate(fileName)
    blockList.sort(reverse = True)
    binList = checker(binList, len(binList), blockList)
    binPrint(binList)

def isSpaceFree(binList, r, c, size):
    if r + size > len(binList[0]):
        return False
    elif c + size > len(binList[0]):
        return False
    for row in range(r, r + size):
        for col in range(c, c + size):
            if binList[r][c] != 0:
              return False
            elif binList[r][c] == size:
                return False
    return True

def checker(binList, gSize, blockList):
    for i in blockList:
        r = 0
        c = 0
        comp = False
        while comp != True:
            check = isSpaceFree(binList, r, c, i)
            if check == True:
                for x in range(c, c+ i):
                    for y in range(r, r+ i):
                        binList[x][y] = i
                comp = True
            else:
                print(c)
                print(r)
                r += 1
                if r > gSize:
                    r = 0
                    c += 1
                    if c > gSize:
                        print("Imcompadible")
                        comp = True
        print(i)
        binPrint(binList)
        input()
    return binList
```

Comment: What's in your input file? 4 3 2 1?

Comment: input file is any assortment of numbers in that format. So "4 1 1 1 5 6" and "3 6 8 7 2 4 5" would both work, along with that you linked

Comment: `itemCreate` makes no sense. What do you expect repeatedly assigning `lst = i` to do? Is that supposed to be appending to `lst`? Or are you only interested in the last line of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to test for open spaces looks in `binList[r][c]` (where `r` is a row value and `c` is a column value). However, the code that sets the values once an open space has been found sets `binList[x][y]` (where `x` is a column value and `y` is a row value).

The latter is wrong. You want to set `binList[y][x]` instead (indexing by row, then column).

That will get you a working solution, but it will still not be exactly what you say you expect (you'll get a reflection across the diagonal). This is because your code updates `r` first, then `c` only when `r` has exceeded the bin size. If you want to place items to the right first, then below, you need to swap them.

I'd suggest using two `for` loops for `r` and `c`, rather than a `while` too, but to make it work in an elegant way you'd probably need to factor out the "find one item's place" code so you could `return` from the inner loop (rather than needing some complicated code to let you break out of both of the nested loops).

Comment: yep that was it, had to flip flop a few of the c's and r's and it worked like a charm! Thanks!